# The implication of $ S(SAT)=2^{\Omega{(n)}} $ Conjecture (5.7 in Wigderson Book)

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

I started to read *Avi Wigderson* book *[Math and Computation](https://www.math.ias.edu/avi/book)*, which get me excited about the following:

> **Conjecture 5.7.** $
> S(SAT)=2^{\Omega{(n)}}
> $,
> where $S$ denotes the size of the smallest Boolean circuits computing it's input, e.g. $SAT$ in the conjecture case.

I didn't find Theorem, Lemma, or anything related to the implication of this conjecture, so my questions are:

- If **Conjecture 5.7.** is **true**, does it imply $P \neq NP$? since its circuits need at least $2^{\Omega(n)}$ to be constructed, which leads to exponential time algorithm, which means $SAT \not\in P$, recalling that $P = NP \iff SAT \in P$, right? any other implications? — *SEE UPDATE.*
- If **Conjecture 5.7.** is **false**, what its implications?

---

**UPDATE:** I found the following theorem:

> **Theorem 7.7.** If $SAT$ cannot be solved by circuits of size $2^{o(n)}$, then $P=BPP$.

An equivalent and more general result here [Impagliazzo, Wigderson 1997](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Eavi/PUBLICATIONS/MYPAPERS/IW97/proc.pdf). If the conjecture is **true** that implies $P=BPP$.

Comment: This is equivalent to the exponential time hypothesis (ETH).

Comment: @Laakeri: I don't think so. ETH is about (uniform) algorithms, whereas this is about circuits. I would call this "non-uniform ETH."

Comment: @HuckBennett I don't know so much in the literature, but somehow it's looks like ETH related to circuits lower bound, as [this report](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2019/169/) say.

Comment: @HuckBennett Yes, you are right

Comment: I think one needs to be a bit careful here in how SAT instances are encoded.

Comment: @KristofferArnsfeltHansen Can you illustrate?

Comment: There is a desceptive discrepancy in notation. In the Impagliazzo–Wigderson theorem, $n$ is the size of the input in bits. In contrast, the circuit size of SAT is normally expressed in terms of $n$ being the number of *variables* of the input CNF. There is an upper bound $2^nN^{O(1)}$ on the circuit size of SAT, where $N$ is the bit-size of the input, hence you *cannot* expect it to require circuit size $2^{\Omega(N)}$, unless you consider some severely restricted version of SAT that can be encoded in $N=O(n)$ bits, but somehow still manages to be exponentially hard. This is quite problematic.

Comment: To put it differently: assume that CNF are encoded in a standard way (with variable indices written in binary, and $O(1)$-bit polarity indicators and separators). Then an $N$-bit CNF contains at most $N/\log N$ distinct variables, hence SAT is solvable in deterministic time $2^{O(N/\log N)}$, and it has circuits of size $2^{O(N/\log N)}$. Thus, the best you can hope for is that SAT requires circuit size $2^{\Omega(N/\log N)}$. (This *is* likely true: e.g., it follows if satisfiability of 3-CNF with $O(n)$ clauses requires circuit size $2^{\Omega(n)}$.) This is *not* enough to give P = BPP. ...

Comment: ... It only implies that BPP is solvable in deterministic quasipolynomial time. (More precisely, it implies $\mathrm{BPP\subseteq DTIME}(n^{O(\log\log n)})$, if my back-of-the-virtual-envelope calculation is correct.)

Comment: Let me also note that I didn’t read the book, but based on the few pages I’ve seen now, this is not a textbook or a research monograph, but a pop-sci book. (E.g., there are no proofs.) Thus, the author is most likely shaving corners of the exposition so that technical correctness does not stand in the way of getting a good story. You should not take it too literally.